# Answering multiple same questions with no accepted answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I've solved a long running problem that a lot of people were asking questions about for almost a year now and I want to let these people know about the solution. It's worthwhile to note that none of these questions (5 or so and there maybe more) have accepted answers.

So do I add the same answer for every question or do I answer one of them and sort of add a link in the others?

I was not sure what to do so I ended up basically copy-pasting the same answer in 4 of them. SO was not that happy because it started asking if I'm a robot.

Did I do the choose to do the wrong thing?

Comment: If you can post the exact same answer to multiple questions, you have to stop and ask yourself if the questions are *duplicates*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If they are truly asking the same question: answer the best one (most generally applicable, most concise, most upvotes, oldest, you pick), wait for an upvote on that answer and then flag the other questions as a duplicate of the one you answered.

Comment: Ah didn't think of that. All of them have ~same number of upvotes and a fair amount of discussion. So now, do I delete all of my answers except for one and hope that thread gets all the traffic for that topic? I'm not sure if that would be for the best.

Comment: My reason being clear, maybe I can keep the answers until one gets accepted and then close others as duplicates? I'm not sure about this SO-wise (am I being arrogant here?). I really just want the solution to reach the most number of people.

Comment: Well reading the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220291/how-to-enable-migrations-ef6-in-an-asp-net-5-project/35889447#35889447) now I'm not that convinced you should have posted it anyway. I know that ASP.NET 5 and EF7 still are a frustrating mess, but that doesn't mean you can just spam your library. Instead explain in your answer what one needs to do to get EF6 migrations to work in ASP.NET 5, and then _perhaps_ link to your library that does that. I don't really see the questions being exact duplicates of each other, either.

Comment: I understand, the problem is migrations can't just be enabled like that. A dnx command line tool is the only solution right now, and because nobody took the time to make one (I'm sure nobody did, I would've been able to find it) I did (because of a real need). But if other people say the same thing then I'd understand.

Comment: That's no problem, but then **mention that in your answer**. Now it just looks like one big bold advertisement for your library, without any explanation why one would use it.

Comment: I see, it was out of frustration I assure you (EF7 kept me up at night a lot of days). So maybe I'll just keep one and add a link to it in other answers. Is this what you think is best?

Comment: _"add a link to it in other answers"_ no, don't do that. First, please rewrite the one you intend to keep into a proper answer that doesn't only say "use my library".

Comment: Answer is now proper (hopefully), I'll delete all others and wait for this one to become accepted, and then mark the others as dups. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help. Make sure they're absolutely a duplicate.